# Creating classes: Why are these ''illegal start of expression'' and ':' expected" errors happening?

Tags: java, class

I'm creating a class for cars that has their make and model, and then every time the accelerator method is accessed it increases the speed by 5. I feel like I'm missing some key part about creating classes of your own, but I'm not sure what! Any help would be great. Here's my code:
        import java.util.Scanner;

```
    public class Car
    {
    public static void main (String[] args);
    {
  //Scanner object
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

  //variables and declarations
  int yearModel;
  String make;
  int speed = 0;

  System.out.println("Enter model year: ");
  yearModel= Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());

  System.out.println("Enter make: ");
  make = kb.nextLine();

  //Car object
  Car car = new Car(yearModel, make, speed);

  System.out.println("Car model year: " + car.getModel() + "/nCar make: " + car.getMake());
  //get speed 5 times
  for (int i = 0; i > 5; i++);
  {
     System.out.println("Car's current speed: " + Accelerate(car.getSpeed()));
  }

  /**
    Accelerator method
    adds five to the speed every time it is accessed
    @param speed car is currently going
    @return new current speed, increased by five
    */
    public int Accelerate(int speed)
    {
    int newSpeed = speed+5;

    return newSpeed;
    }
```

}

```
  /**
  Constructor
  @param yearModel holds the cards model year
  @param make holds the make of the car
  */
  public Car(int yearModel, String make, int speed)
  {
    yearModel = yearModel;
    make = make;
    speed = speed;
  }

    //getSpeed method, returns current speed of car
    public int getSpeed();
    {
     return speed;
    }

    //getYear method, returns model year @return year model
    public int getModel()
    {
     return yearModel;
    }

    //getModel method, @return make
    public String getMake()
    {
     return make;
    }
 }
```

and here are the errors I'm getting:

```
Car.java:37: error: illegal start of expression
    public int Accelerate(int speed)
    ^
Car.java:37: error: ';' expected
    public int Accelerate(int speed)
                         ^
Car.java:37: error: ';' expected
    public int Accelerate(int speed)
```

Any help would be great, I'm pretty new at this

Comment: You can't have a method inside a method in Java. Looks like it's the case for the Accelerate method which is inside the main method. Move it out.

Comment: You're missing a closing "}" in your main method, which means it looks like you're creating methods within a method, which is illegal

Comment: remove semicolon from this line `for (int i = 0; i > 5; i++);`

Comment: First thing to do is set up whatever IDE you're using to indent your code for you. It'll make it *much* easier to see this sort of thing.

Comment: Usually because you've got a missing/misplaced `{`, `}`, or `;`, or because you have something outside of a method that should be in a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You placed a semi-colon after a methods prototype:

```
public static void main (String[] args);
```

Same problem here:

```
public int getSpeed();
```

Also missing an ending brace after your static main method:

```
    for (int i = 0; i > 5; i++) ;
    {
        System.out.println("Car's current speed: " + Accelerate(car.getSpeed()));
    }
}
```

Also the semi-colon after the `for` statement shouldn't be there :D You must really like semi-colons.

Comment: Okay, that's one problem, keep going...